# Create ERD Of MS CRM Database

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, erd

Is there any way to auto create **ERD** of any existing CRM applicaton.
I have **MS CRM 11 On Premise** and want to take a short look on entities and their relationship diagram. Do we need to create it manually by digging one by one entity and their relationship or is there any other way or any tool do it ?
OR This is not a valid question at all ?

Ideas will be appreciated if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a great feature in Lucidchart called [automated ERD import](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Hh7Z-TT2jc) which could be useful though you'd need permission to query the system tables to get the table definitions etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I try this free of cost ? Without payment, Can I create ERD of my existing CRM application ?

Comment: fez: I want to auto create not want to draw manually. That is actually requirement.

Comment: I am able to run the SDK messsage for my CRM and it created a nice ERD, ofcourse it took time much as CRM having around 300 entities :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602918(v=crm.5).aspx) on MSDN. The section at the bottom titled Generate Entity Diagrams with the Metadata Diagram Tool describes how to use a program from the SDK to generate an ERD.

Comment: I am able to run the SDK messsage for my CRM and it created a nice ERD, ofcourse it took much time as CRM having around 300 entities :)